# Is geom_text the best way for labeling bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

https://gofile.io/?c=rvB9yp

I'm trying to add labels to the bars , the label should be the number of observation (interval column) per sample, for example : sample NE1 has 7 times "30 to 60"... and so on.

I tried the code below:

```
limit <- data$months + 5 ## set limit for geom_text

ggplot(data, aes( x = reorder(interval, months), y=months,fill = SAMPLE))+ 
geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", size=.4, color = 'black')+
xlab('intervals (months)')+
ylab('months')+
geom_text(aes(label= SAMPLE, y = limit),
position=position_dodge(0.9), size=3,angle = 90,check_overlap = TRUE)
```

I always get this!

https://ibb.co/8cjZDx3

any suggestions? maybe geom_text is not the best way to do that??

THANKS S

Comment: What do you want it to look like?  `geom_text` is the appropriate way to do what you want.

Comment: I wanted the number of observations per SAMPLE not the sample name..

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a way to get it without modifying your data, as it seems like `geom_text` will not let you combine a stat for `label` with a prescribed `y`.

The following accomplishes what you need, I think:

```
data <- data %>% dplyr::group_by(interval, SAMPLE) %>% dplyr::summarise(months = max(months), nobs = n()) 

ggplot(data, aes( x = reorder(interval, months),y = months, fill = SAMPLE))+ 
  geom_bar( position="dodge", stat="identity", size=.4, color = 'black') +
  geom_text(aes(label = nobs), position = position_dodge(.9), hjust = -.5, size=3,angle = 90,check_overlap = TRUE) +
  xlab('intervals (months)')+
  ylab('months')
```

Comment: Fabulous Thanks a lot!